# How to implement sharedPreferences with dagger 2 in presenter layer without context?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, dagger-2, mvp

How to implement sharedpreferences with dagger and MVP, most of the tutorials are writing the sharedpreferences in the Activity or providing the context to presenter.

what i need is to see example:

- what should i write into my `presenter` to get the sharedPreference
  without using the `Context`.
- how the `module` will look like.
- Do i need to call the `Component` from `Application` or with every
  activity to provide the context.

**===Update===**

As **PPartisan** mentioned in his answer that i should't include the **`sharedPreference`** in the `Presenter`.

So how can i abstract the **`SharedPreferences`** behind an API

**===Update 2===**

Thanks for your answer **PPartisan** it really worked very good, could you please check my code if its perfectly written, or need any adjustments.

**MainActivity**

```java
 @Inject
    MainPresenter presenter;

    AppComponent component;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();

        component = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .build();

        component.inject(this);

    }
```

**AppModule**

```java
@Module
public abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    abstract Repository bindRepository(SharedPrefsRepository prefs);

    @Binds
    abstract MainPresenterListener listener(MainPresenterListener mListener);

    @Provides
    static SharedPreferences prefs(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

}
```

**ContextModule**

```java
@Module
public class ContextModule {

    private Context context;

    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```java
@Component (modules = {AppModule.class, ContextModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its simplest form (and assuming `Context` is already part of your dependency graph), then in your module:

```
@Provides static SharedPreferences prefs(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```

And in your Presenter:

```
class Presenter {

    private final SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Inject
    Presenter(SharedPreferences prefs) {
       this.prefs = prefs;
    }

}
```

There's more you can do with this however. For instance, you can scope the `Presenter` to the lifecycle of the `View` (i.e. an `Activity` or `Fragment`). Also, a "Presenter" in its purest form should know nothing of Android components, so you may want to abstract the `SharedPreferences` behind an API of your own.

**Edit:** Here's an example of how you might abstract your data persistence so you Presenter can remain unaware of Android components:

Create a suitable interface (this just persists and returns Strings, so modify it accordingly):

```
interface Repository {
    String read();
    void write(String value);
}
```

Create an instance of this `interface` that delegates to `SharedPreferences`:

```
class SharedPrefsRespository implements Repository {

    private static final String KEY = "a_key";

    private final SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Inject
    SharedPrefsRepository(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    @Override
    String read() {
        return prefs.getString(KEY, "");
    }

    @Override
    void write(String value) {
        prefs.edit()
            .putString(KEY, value == null ? "" : value)
            .apply();
    }

}
```

Tell Dagger that this implementation of `Repository` is the one you want to use by adding the following to your module (ensure your module is `abstract`):

```
@Binds abstract Repository repository(SharedPrefsRepository prefs);
```

In your `Presenter`, inject `Repository` rather than `SharedPreferences`:

```
class Presenter {

    private final Repository repo;

    private View view;

    @Inject
    Presenter(Repository repo) {
       this.repo = repo;
    }

    void attach(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        showUserName();
    }

    //Example of how you might use this repo on something you want to persist
    //Imagine a user has entered their username and clicked save...
    void onSaveUserName(String username) {
        repo.write(username);
    }

    private void showUserName() {
        view.showUsername(repo.read());
    }

}
```

Comment: So the SharedPreference shouldn't be in the presenter? 
could you please clarify how can i abstract the SharedPreferences behind an API.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer **PPartisan** it really worked very good, could you please check my code edited in the description, if its perfectly written, or need any adjustments.

Comment: You can use the `BindsInstance` annotation in place of your `ContextModule` if you like. I can't vouch this [this article](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe), but it looks as though it covers it. Also, you don't need this, `@Binds abstract MainPresenterListener listener(MainPresenterListener mListener);`, as it's just "providing" itself. Otherwise yeah it look fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciated.